# How to connect an Android app with a c++ program on pc via USB

Tags: android, c++, stream, usb

Require a method of connecting an android app with a C++ program on PC via USB, which would allow the android app to send a constant stream of real time data (mostly integer values) to a c++ program on PC via USB and carry out actions accordingly. I know it is easier to do this by wifi or bluetooth, but I want to carry out the connection using USB.

I have searched the net alot for similar questions, and tried many code, but non of them have worked for me. I would greatly appreciate an example code for the c++ portion, and it's android counterpart that allow for this to be done easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the USB Tethering option on the phone. This should work with Android 4.4 and the most popular Linux Distributions out of the box. Then you are able use TCP/IP between Android and the PC. You could use an UDP multicast based protocol for service discovery (e.g. Multicast DNS, NSD or SSDP) if you need to avoid entering IP addresses on one side.

Comment: Can we have both, android usb thethered to my pc, and, a wired lan connection? Or is it only one of those at a time?

Comment: _Yes_ and _no_. I just tried it. _Yes_ you can have both connections at the same time. _No_, because it replaces your default gateway routing entry on the PC (which is generally useful for tethering but in this case probably unwanted). So all internet trafiic is routed through the android device. If the android phone is put into flight mode, this happens as well. So if you need an internet connection on the PC this is solution is probably a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to setup your pc application to talk to the android device as an android accessory. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

This will allow both applications to send whatever data they want over usb, Google do provide source code for doing this with the accessory development kit http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html

I don't have any example source code but there might be some out there if you search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADB and call custom commands on your Android device. This commands should just type integers to stdout. As an option, you can use standard shell commands like `cat` and make your Android app write output integers to files in some directory where ADB can read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Android behave like a USB device with a USB CDC (ACM) interface, which is seen as a serial port on the PC (COMx on Windows, /dev/ttyXXX on Linux). On C++ (PC) side, this would be "regular" serial port handling, while on Android there are several libraries for such purposes, though I never used one so I can't recommend any.